# Why is div filling content bottom to top

Tags: html, css, display

Why is the `div` on the left filling its content from the bottom to the top? I am aware that I can use the CSS `float` property to make the two divs tops align. I am just curious about what piece of this snippet is causing the left `div` to align with the bottom of the other one.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbyePP

```css
.form-row {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  /*float: left;*/
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <span>Soup?</span>
  <label><input type="radio" value="Yes">Yes<label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" value="No">No<label><br>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <span>Salad?</span>
  <label><input type="radio" value="Yes">Yes<label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" value="No">No<label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" value="Maybe">Maybe<label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top`.  `inline-block` elements respond to `vertical-align`, and I believe that default is `baseline`, which would cause bottom alignment.

Comment: Also you can change inline-block to inline-flex to get what you want

Comment: Your html is invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` value for an `inline-block` element is `baseline`. Just add `vertical-align:top;` to it.

```css
.form-row {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  vertical-align:top;
}

span, label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <span>Soup?</span>
  <label><input type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="No">No</label>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <span>Salad?</span>
  <label><input type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="No">No</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="Maybe">Maybe</label>
</div>
```

Also, make sure you are closing your tags correctly. Additionally, you can remove all the breaks if you just set `label` to `display:block;`

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: @Rob you are correct, answer has been updated accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Default is baseline. Try vertical-align-top